# Can a Pod with an affinity for one node's label, but without a toleration for that node's taint, mount to that node?

Tags: kubernetes

Say you have Node1 with taint `node1taint:NoSchedule` and label `node1specialkey=asdf`.
And Node2 with no taints.

Then you create PodA with affinity to Node1:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: PodA
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node1specialKey
                operator: Exists
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: PodA
```

Which pod should the node schedule to? Will the affinity override the taint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The pod will not schedule anywhere, because it does not tolerate Node1's taint and it does not have an affinity for Node2.

Here is the missing pod taint that would, in combination with the affinity, successfully schedule PodA on Node1.

```
tolerations:
- key: "node1taint"
  operator: "Exists"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

A taint is more powerful than an affinity. The pod needs the toleration, too, because affinity alone is not strong enough here in Kubernetes-land.

Comment: Affinities have two modes, "required" and "preferred". As the name implies, "required" is required :) And that's the one you used in your example. Preferred would allow the affinity to be violated.

Comment: Ah great, thank you! @coderanger So would the "preferred" affinity have scheduled PodA onto Node1 or Node2?

Comment: Node 2, taints are always a hard requirement but the preferred affinity would have just not been met.